# How to setup onedrive with office 365 for sync

Tags: office-365, sync, onedrive-for-business

Is there a way to setup one drive business with office 365 where each folder is mapped to respected office 365 document library. For example, if I have following file share folders

```
Contracts
AFE
Agreements
Budgets
Marketing
Operations
Properties
```

I would like one drive to sync Contracts from file share to Contracts Library in Office 365 and so forth. Is it possible and How?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you duplicating your data?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I think. This is what the boss want.

Comment: If your boss asked you to jump off a building or commit fraud I would hope you wouldn't do it. Why should you implement something that goes against accepted business practice and will cost the company both time and money both now and in the future?

Comment: Since we are talking about sync, not copy pasting information, I do not see the value in your comments @aboba

Comment: He is talking about a copy of the data on a network drive synced to an office 365 location and not just a local sync copy for offline use, which is why I have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an answer to this. http://spsync.net and looks like the tool let you create different sync job per this print shot.

more on this: http://blog.mwiedemeyer.de/category/SPSync

http://blog.mwiedemeyer.de/post/2012/04/10/Sync-SharePoint-Document-Libraries-in-Windows-Explorer-like-Dropbox

Answer (score 0):

What you may be able to do is set up a batch file, maybe on your computer at first for testing purposes.  The BATch file would then have a couple of commands in it to map the OneDrive location to a drive letter, let's say X:.  Then the next command would map the Office 365 / SharePoint folder to another letter, lets say Y:.  Then a robocopy command could follow that.

For example:

```
Net use x: "http://path.to.onedrive/Contract"
Net use y: "http://path.tosp/Contracts"
robocopy x: y: /mir
```

To get the actual path for where these drives should be mapped to you can use the "Open With Windows Explorer" in the OneDrive and Document Library in question.  Don't be surprised if the end up being "\something\WebDavWWW..." which is fine.  That bat file then could be added to any computer and then tied in to a Windows task scheduler.

An alternative or perhaps after the first run of the batch file you may also want to investigate workflows on the OneDrive library to see if you can implement a workflow which would copy the file to a separate location after a new file is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the new OneDrive Sync Client